# Static array unity

Tags: arrays, static, unityscript

I am trying to make a static array in unity that holds an integer in each element, however upon testing the array seems to be new for each object that accesses it.

```js
static var tiles: float[];


function Start() {
  tiles = new float[6];
  tiles[1] = 1;
  Random();
}

function Random() {
  i = Random.Range(1, 6);
  if (i == 1) {
    tiles[1] ++;
  } else if (i == 2) {
    tiles[2] ++;
    print(tiles[2]);
  } else if (i == 3) {
    tiles[3] ++;
  } else if (i == 4) {
    tiles[4] ++;
  } else if (i == 5) {
    tiles[5] ++;
  } else if (i == 6) {
    tiles[6] ++;
  }

}
```

Comment: Not an answer but you can replace that whole `if` statement with this: `tiles[i]++`

Answer (score 1):

When are you checking the values? How many objects on the scene have this script attached to it? It seems to me that you have the script attached to multiple objects and Random() is executed multiple times.
Ex.

- Obj1 --> Start() --> populate static array
- Obj2 --> Start() -->
  re-populate static array
- Obj3 --> Start() --> re-populate static
  array

In the end, all objects will have the same static array, generated by Obj3

Comment: Yeah, the problem seems to be that he's executing this like `tiles = new float[6];` every time.

Comment: Exactly.. Start() is executed for every GameObject in the scene that has your script attached